# How to view jTable selected rows in PDF form

Tags: java, jtable, netbeans-8

I'm new at programming and now I'm trying a project in jTable where I will select a row and it will fetch the data and it will be open in pdf form or document . I have no idea how to do that.

This is what I want to happened.

```
|** Name    | Book Borrowed       |Date of Return |Date Today**
:--------    :-----------          :---------      :---------
| Billy     | Webster Dictionary  |July 28, 2023  |August 15, 2023
| Cecille   | Encyclopedia A-Bh   |August 30, 2023|August 15, 2023
```

If I select Billy, it will open in pdf or document.
Like this.

Document sample:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMhqV.png]

I'd really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: *I have no idea how to do that.* - do what? There are multiple steps to your question.  1) you need to create a JFrame with a JTable 2) You need to be able to select an item for which you want to create the notice. 3) You need to create a pdf document based on the selected row in the table. Solve one step at a time. If you have a problem with a step then ask a specific question about that step.

Comment: I would suggest having a look at jasper reports

Comment: @camickr
In the 3rd step you mentioned, that's where I have a problem.
how to do your third step, thanks.

Comment: Why pdf particularly?

Comment: I have no idea. So your question has nothing to do with a JTable. The question is how to create a PDF document in Java. Keep your questions simple and straight to the point. You have been given a suggestion to use Jasper reports. I don't know what it is but that would be a place to start I guess.